# UITableView CoreData - Sort Descriptor not affecting Headers

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I pray to god someone can help! I've been stuck on this for weeks now.

I have a tableview representing coredata objects. At the top of the table view, I have a segmented controller representing different ways to sort the data. On change, the segmented controller updates the arrangement of the table.

I have a problem where, upon adding data, everything looks ok - until I change sorting methods. After leaving "date" and going to "location" (for example), if you return to date, the HEADERS don't match the dates... the dates should appear in descending order with headers that MATCH...

BEFORE CLICKING "LOCATION"
[image: Before changing segmented controller]

AFTER CLICKING "LOCATION" AND RETURNING TO "DATE"
[image: After changing segmented controller]

Here's the pertinent code (at least I think so...)

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlChange(sender: AnyObject) {
    //call custom class for overlay loading indicator
    let progressHUD = ProgressHUD(text: "Sorting")
    self.view.addSubview(progressHUD)

    //put the table load on a different thread for processing
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        self.getFetchResultsController()

        self.tableView.reloadData()

        //after tableview is loaded, execute this
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.view.sendSubviewToBack(progressHUD)
            progressHUD.hide()
        })
    })
}

func getFetchResultsController(){

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Place")

    switch self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        let sortByDate = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortByDate]
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        println("sorted by date")
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 30

        aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionDateHdr", cacheName: nil)

        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    case 1:
        let sortByState = NSSortDescriptor(key: "state", ascending: true)
        let sortByAOI = NSSortDescriptor(key: "aoiData.aoiName", ascending: true)
        let sortByDate = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortByState, sortByAOI, sortByDate]
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        println("sorted by AOI, then date")
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 30

        aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "state", cacheName: nil)

        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    case 2:
        let sortByTail = NSSortDescriptor(key: "tailNum", ascending: false)
        let sortByDate = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortByTail, sortByDate]
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        println("sorted by tail, then date")
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 30

        aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "tailNum", cacheName: nil)

        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    default:
        println("no coredata object to query in fetchData")
    }

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !self.aFetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error) {
        abort()
    }
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.aFetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return aFetchedResultsController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"

    var cell : CustomTableViewCell!
    cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    var curPlace = aFetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AllPlaces

    if curPlace.hasImage == true {
        image = UIImage(data: curPlace.images.imageData)!
    } else {
    image = UIImage(named: "Placeholder")!
    }

    cell.loadItem(curPlace.hasImage, aoi: curPlace.aoiData.aoiName, date: curPlace.date, city: curPlace.city, state: curPlace.state, arrOrDep: curPlace.arrOrDep)
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Blue

    if indexPath.row == (aFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.count - 1)
    {
        self.getFetchResultsController()
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    //self.getFetchResultsController()
    let sectionInfo = self.aFetchedResultsController.sections![section] as! NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
    return sectionInfo.name
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in typical fashion as soon as I cave and ask for help I figured it out. Not sure why this worked but here is what I did -

1.) In the "AllPlaces" class, I added a function that just looked at the date and returned the value of MMMM yyyy as a string. I called this sectionID.

```
    func sectionID() -> String {
    var aformatter = NSDateFormatter()
    aformatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"

    return aformatter.stringFromDate(date)
}
```

2.) I was previously using a property called sectionDateHdr, which was a string format of the same "date" variable, in the same MMMM yyyy format. For some reason, using sectionID instead of sectionDateHdr caused the table to correctly label the headers.

I really have no clue why.. but I am so relieved it is finally working. I'm guessing it has something to do with when the values are set that get passed through the fetchResultsController.

2 weeks later!!! SOLVED!